# How to create nested models and get nested JSON output in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have an API currently built that works great for viewing, creating, updating, and deleting data. But I have run into a roadblock while trying to create my last model. The model needs to have a field that has lots of nested data in it. Here is the data I have to store:

```
{
    "years": {
        "2017": {
            "hours_budgeted": 1000,
            "hours_actual": 1200,
            "quarters": {
                "1": {
                    "hours_budgeted": 250,
                    "hours_actual": 300,
                    "weeks": {
                        "1": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "2": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "3": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "4": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "5": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "6": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "7": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "8": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "9": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "10": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "11": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "12": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                        "13": {
                            "hours_budgeted": 10,
                            "hours_actual": 12,
                        }
                    }
                }
                "2": {
                    "hours_budgeted": 250,
                    "hours_actual": 300,
                    "weeks": {

                    }
                }
                "3": {
                    "hours_budgeted": 250,
                    "hours_actual": 300,
                    "weeks": {

                    }
                }
                "4": {
                    "hours_budgeted": 250,
                    "hours_actual": 300,
                    "weeks": {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        "2018": {

        }
        "2019": {

        }
    }
}
```

I am absolutely stumped as to how to create a model that can store this data. I have looked online and found nothing on the subject. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django PostgreSQL specific field called `JSONField`

#### models.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class YourModel(models.Model):
    # Your other fields here
    data = JSONField()
```

#### views.py

```
YourModel.objects.create(data=data)
```

Querying is also very easy... `Dog.objects.filter(data__years='2017')`

And one more thing is Django Rest Framework >= 3.3 [JSONField serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield) included.

Or use the traditional way to define your model. And update the fields.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a module named JSONField since I'm using SQLite, but same idea.